# Django migrating from sqlite to MySQL. Fixture error

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm trying to export my SQLite data and then import into MySQL (after making the appropriate changes to the settings.py file). Here is the error I see when trying to import the data:

```
python manage.py loaddata < datadump.json

CommandError: No database fixture specified. Please provide the path of at least one fixture in     the command line.
```

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the '<'

> python manage.py loaddata datadump.json

Comment: That was easy. Nice catch. Thank you.